# How can I read in a Prolog term with unquoted strings?

Tags: prolog

I have some files of Prolog term dumps that were written out with `quoted` being false, for example:

```
[4a, 5b, 6c].
```

Now I'm trying to read these back in as terms:

```
?- open('test.txt',read,In),
|    read_term(In,X,[]).
ERROR: test.txt:1:2: Syntax error: Operator expected
```

Of course it errors, as `4a` is not a valid Prolog atom. I'm wondering if there's any way (perhaps via one of the massively big `read_term/3` options, or anything else I'm unaware of) I can force read these invalid terms in as strings or no dice?

Comment: There is no way to do this in general. Think of the atom `'1+1'` which now reads `1+1` and thus is a valid Prolog term meaning `+(1,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use predicates [read_line_to_string/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=read_line_to_string/2), [split_string/4](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=split_string/4), and [include/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3):

```
read_line_to_list(Stream, List) :-
    read_line_to_string(Stream, String),
    split_string(String, ", ", "[]", Substrings),
    include([T]>>(T \= ""), Substrings, List).
```

Example:

```
?- open('test.txt', read, In), read_line_to_list(In, L), close(In).
In = <stream>(000001545d01c9e0),
L = ["4a", "5b", "6c"].
```